# Issue with contact key

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

While connecting marketing cloud and sales cloud contact object contact key will be auto- generate ?

If yes, so in my sync DE  there is one field "_ContactKey" has been generated.

Now i want to use same fields in my standard DE so i am taking the same field name but its giving me an error "Field Name cannot begin with an underscore".

How do i get the exact field from sync DE to standard DE?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to manually import / create subscribers for your new Standard Data Extension?

What we generally tell our clients to do with Synchronized SF Data Extensions is to create Filtered Data Extensions from them. This way you can send to them, etc. and all of the fields in the Synchronized SF Data Extension will populate into your newly created Filtered Data Extension.

If you'd just like to bring over everyone whom you can email, we recommend using an operator like "Email *is not null*" as your filter.

This will bring in that "_ContactKey" field and you can then use it for the Send Relationship.

Let me know if that answers your question!